# How to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) for a long command separated by ;

Tags: android

I have to execute an adb command using Runtime.getRuntime().exec:

`sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 0;sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 53 325;sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 54 891;sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 58 71;sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 48 71;sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0;sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 4294967295;sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0;`

I am sending this string:

```
String cmd = "sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 0;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 53 325;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 54 891;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 58 71;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 48 71;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 4294967295;" +
                    "sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0;";
call(cmd);
```

in this call function:

```
private void call( String cmd) {

  Process ans_call;
  InputStreamReader cmd_reader;
  BufferedReader cmd_bufferedReader;
  String line = null;
  try {
    sendMainUIMessage(MSG_KPI_UI_UPDATE_REQUEST, null, cmd);
    mLogWriter.writeDiagnoseLog(cmd);
    ans_call = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    NotifyRunning(ans_call);
    cmd_reader = new InputStreamReader(ans_call.getInputStream());
    cmd_bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(cmd_reader);

    while (((line = cmd_bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) {
        sendMainUIMessage(MSG_KPI_UI_UPDATE_REQUEST, null, line + "\n");
        mLogWriter.writeDiagnoseLog(line);              
    }  //end of while

    ans_call.waitFor();
    NotifyEnd(ans_call);
    cmd_reader.close();
    cmd_bufferedReader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Ping test Fail: InterruptedException");
  } //end of try

}
```

The code runs fine but I don't see the command getting executed. Can someone point out the problem?

Comment: Always include a tag for the primary language you're working with. Also, hover the pointer above a tag to see a definition. `cmd` is a Windows command shell and is not related to this question.

Comment: adb is an interface.  The command you want to run here is an "adb command" only in the sense that it only works when using the semi-elevated privileges available through the adb interface, and not with the highly restricted privileges of 3rd party applications running on the device.  To run it from an application, you would need to use a privilege escalation hack, such as a modified "su" shim.

Answer (score 0):

Your application does not have permissions to write to the `/dev/input/event2`